# Invoking java jar from shell script in cloud foundry

Tags: java, shell, cloud-foundry

I have a cloud foundry application which has shell exec(builder) through which i can execute shell scripts.

My cf application first downloads the shell script and java jar to CF local (ex:/app/lib/) directory from s3 and it executes the shell script.In shell script i am triggering a java program and it fails with "Shell command returned a non-zero exit value: 127 error" .

```
cat my_shell_java.sh -> 
#!/bin/bash 
java -jar myjar.jar com.abc.def.myClass
```

i have tried with below command as well but same error.

```
cat my_shell_java.sh -> 
#!/bin/bash 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java java -jar myjar.jar com.abc.def.myClass
```

But if i execute shell which creates a folder in CF , it works fine.

```
cat my_shell_mkdir.sh ->
#!/bin/bash 
mkdir /app/lib
```

Can some one pls help me on how can i execute a java program from shell script in Cloud foundry.

Comment: I have resolved this by locating java buildpack for my app ex: /app/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java -jar myjar.jar com.abc.def.myClass and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can just push the java app archive using `cf push`. 
What is the need for the shell script? 
I am just curious....

Comment: thanks for ur time on this..we have an existing spring bath solution runs in EC2 and we want to move the same to CF. so we are trying to run the same in CF and understand the limitations.